# Adding a color picker in UIAlertView

Tags: ios, iphone, uialertview, color-picker

In my iPhone application, i want a color picker to be added on a button click pop up. Can anyone please suggest how to proceed with it. Read several online materials but not finding a good start point.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use kartech/Colorpicker , here is link

https://github.com/kartech/colorpicker

Comment: Don't use alert view in any manner. Create you custom view.
Refer here https://github.com/jjxtra/DRColorPicker